# how can I post html content to wordpress with xmlrpc?

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, html-post

I've got a script to post some data to wordpress using xmlrpc.

If I use a simple string for the body like "This is a test" it works fine.

However, if it has any HTML formatting in it, it gets horribly mangled when trying to add the post.

How do I post html content to wordpress with xmlrpc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a plugin that fixes a problem with some versions of an xml library that strips html:   [Plugin – LibXML2 Fix | Joseph Scott](http://josephscott.org/code/wordpress/plugin-libxml2-fix/)