# Uploading content to wordpress via xmlrpc: how to post markup?

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

Using python-wordpress-xmlrpc to post content to a wordpress blog, the [documentation](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org) is good except that it only shows trivial plain text content. If I use HTML markup in content then the HTML tags get escaped (converted to "&lt ;" etc), and so do not display properly. Can anyone suggest a way to avoid this?

The only question I've seen that addresses this is [3055915](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055915/how-can-i-post-html-content-to-wordpress-with-xmlrpc) which was six years ago: it refers to a bug fixed in libxml that must surely be fixed now.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am looking to post it via markdown